# Using Timers for Blink & Count

Tags: c, timer, interrupt, atmega, avrdude

I'm creating part of a program right now for a personal project. This is my first year ACTUALLY coding and have been studying for hours to understand many concepts so please be nice and try not to be rude as others have...

The project of mine is an AVRDUDE using a chip called ATMEGA328P in a program called Microchip studios.

[This project is having 3 LED count every time a switch is pressed, I should have them count continuously and change to the next number every second using a TIMER 1.

**counting in binary from 0-8 then rolling over **

I need some help on one aspect of it which is using interrupts after I have already created a blinking LED to use a TIMER0 instead of delays.

I have made my fourth LED flash at 5Hz which is the blinking part of my code include below at the end of this question.

Now the problem I am running into is trying to create interrupts for the 3 LEDS count every time a switch is pressed, I should instead have them continually count, changing to the next number approximately every second, using TIMER1.]

This is my code for the project
Again please be nice and at least lead me in some type of direction...

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#define F_CPU 1000000UL 
int global = 0 ;

volatile uint8_t overflow0;  // Variable for counting overflows for first timer
volatile uint8_t overflow1;    // Variable for counting overflows for second timer



void FirstTimer()  // Initialize Timer 1 
    {
        TCCR0B |= (1<<CS02) | (1<<CS00);  // Prescaler of 1024
        TCNT0 = 0;
    }

void SecondTimer() //Initialize Timer 2
    {
        TCCR1B |= (1<<CS11) | (1<<CS10);
        TCNT1 = 0;
    }

    

int main(void)
        {
            DDRB |= (1 << DDB0);
    
        FirstTimer();  // Calling timer 1 and 2 initialization
        SecondTimer();
    
        while (1)
        {

            {
                if (TCNT0 >= 195) // Amount of ticks needed
                {
                    PORTB ^= (1 << PORTB0); //LED on
                    TCNT0 = 0; //Reset counter
                }
            }
        

            {
                if (TCNT1 >= 15625) // Ticks needed
                {
                TCNT1 = 0; // Timer reset
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: First, I would group all your includes together at the top before your `#define` statement. This will make your code more readable. Second, when you say 3 LEDs I am assuming this is counting in binary from 0-8 then rolling over and you want each number represented?

Comment: Yes, I have now updated my question

Comment: I don't see what the `volatile uint8_t` (both of them) or the `int global` variables are used for. Second I do not see interrupt service routine definitions. Take a look at this for implementing Timer ISR: https://exploreembedded.com/wiki/AVR_Timer_Interrupts

Answer (score 0):

An approach you could use is keeping a count variable (unsigned char - assuming 8 bit register width) and in your Timer ISR simply increment the count and write that value to the output register. Once count > 8 set to zero.

Configure the Timer mode to trigger on overflow w/ reset to zero.

Then you do some basic math using the clock speed and timer ceiling (overflow value) to calculate the frequency you want the overflow ISR to occur (increment the LED count values).

Note that for this to work the LEDs need to be on the first 3 pins.

i.e.

```
P1.0 = LED1
P1.1 = LED2
P1.2 = LED3
...
```

If not connected like this then you can still make it work with additional bit manipulation (shifts and masks).